# multiply different dataframe column labels / index lenght

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to multiply the two following dataframe:

df1:

```
currency
BTC       151.747134
ETH       612.943278
XRP    876533.361796
```

df2:

```
               balance
currency              
BCH       3.110515e+04
BTC       1.249170e+06
ETH       4.332074e+04
XRP       3.081000e+01
QASH      4.565000e+00
AUD       7.104848e-01
CNY       1.433651e-01
EUR       1.174428e+00
HKD       1.283253e-01
IDR       5.674280e-05
INR       1.334581e-02
JPY       9.441869e-03
PHP       2.033362e-02
SGD       7.227208e-01
USD       1.000000e+00
```

I know that the two df columns names do not match. I tried the following code:

```
df2.rename(columns=['df1_column_name']) * df1
```

error:

```
items = [func(x) for x in index]
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I am only interested in the index located in the first dataframe for the output. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add expected output of the example above as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiple 2 Series by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html), second `DataFrame` select by column name for `Series` and for index only by `df1.index` add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print (type(df1))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (type(df2))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

s = df1.mul(df2['balance'].reindex(df1.index))
print (s)
currency
BTC    1.895580e+08
ETH    2.655316e+07
XRP    2.700599e+07
dtype: float64
```